# How to show an activity appearing from the bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-emulator

From one of my activity I need to present another activity such that it should start appearing from the bottom of the screen, just like the presentmodel animation in iPhone. Is it possible in android? How?

Comment: You can refer [this article](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343) for Android animations.

Comment: Refer http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343 for android animations.